# Почему происходит сортировка списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как-то я писал довольно простой код, лабораторную работу для учебного заведения.
Писал дома, на Python 3.7.3 (win 8.1 64-bit), в учебном заведении была же версия 3.7.0 (win 7 64-bit).
Я частично в курсе про разницу `sorted()` и `List.sort()`, но при этом не понял, почему 3.7.3 выдала мне отсортированный список без повторяющихся элементов, а 3.7.0 выдала просто список без повторяющихся элементов. Почему же это произошло?
Часть кода, выдавшего такой результат:

```
def Add(updateLabs, Data):
    Labs = Data["Tasks"]
    Labs.extend(updateLabs)
    Data.update({
        "Tasks": sorted(list(set(Labs)))
    })
    writeFile('json', Data, 'Magazine.json')
```

В итоговый вариант пошло:

```
def Add(updateLabs, Data):
    Labs = Data["Tasks"]
    Labs.extend(updateLabs)
    Labs.sort()
    Data.update({
        "Tasks": list(set(Labs))
    })
    writeFile('json', Data, 'Magazine.json')
```

Но пока я игрался, пытаясь понять проблему, у меня вышел такой код:
(Python 3.7.3 запуск из IDLE, как и весь остальной код)

```
Labs = [7, 9, 18, 2, 5, 1]
Test = list(set(Labs))
print(Test)
```

И его я уже точно не понял. Почему Test идет отсортированным?

Comment: Потому что повезло. Множества (`set`) по определению не имеют никакой конкретной сортировки; как питону захочется — в том порядке и выведется

Comment: Сейчас я попробовал следующие:
```python
import random;
Labs = [random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(100)];
Test = list(set(Labs));
print(Test);
```
На выходе было: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]` это тоже случайность и вольность Python?

Comment: Это особенности конкретной реализации питона в вашей конкретной операционной системе. Запустите этот код, например, в PyPy под линуксом — и получится `[5, -5, -2, -1, -4, 6, -10, 1, 2, -9, -8, 3, 9, -7, 10, -6, -3, 8, 4, 0]` потому что там другая реализация объектов `set`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь стало яснее

Comment: Только что запустил на Linux Python 3.7.0 Довольно странный вывод: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -10, -9, -8, -7, -1, -5, -4, -3, -2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хэш целого числа - это само значения этого числа, поэтому по множеству числа распределятся последовательно. Но ожидать такого поведения не стоит, так как множества упорядоченности не гарантируют.

Comment: А вот с PyPy такие рассуждения не прокатили

Comment: Спасибо Сергей, теперь стало более понятно! Я не планировал использовать такое поведение, просто стало интересно почему так произошло, куда стоит двигать внимание и размышления